# If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, for any $x_{1},...,x_{n}\in [a,b]$ exist $c\in [a,b]$ s.t $f(c)=\frac{f(x_{1})+...+f(x_{n})}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

My issue is that I don't understand this problem, so I don't know how to attack it. Could you give me some hints on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact, by Weierstrass theorem $f$ attains a maximum and a minimum on $[a,b]$. Let's call them $m$ and $M$ respectively. We can say that

$\dfrac{f(x_1)+\ldots+f(x_n)}{n}\le \dfrac{\overbrace{M+\ldots+M}^{n\text{ times}}}{n}=M$ and

$\dfrac{f(x_1)+\ldots+f(x_n)}{n}\ge \dfrac{\overbrace{m+\ldots+m}^{n \text{ times}}}{n}=m$

Can you take it from here? Hint:

> It involves the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval, so there exists $m,M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m\leq M$ and $f([a,b])=[m,M]$. Also observe $\frac{f(x_1)+ \dots + f(x_n)}{n}$ is between $m$ and $M$ for any $x_1,\ldots ,x_n\in [a,b]$ so we can say

> by IVT the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you don't understand, so if you can try to explain more about your problem, it'll be better for both.
As for the solution to this problem, this is a direct result from the continuity of $f$. 
WLOG, $f(x_n) \ge f(x_{n-1}) \ge... \ge f(x_1)$ 
$\Rightarrow f(x_1) \le y:=\frac{ f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)}{n} \le f(x_{n})$ 
So by the continuity of $f$, there is at least a $c$ between $x_1$ and $x_n$ such that : $f(c)=y$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_k)$ be a convergent sequence in $[a,b]$. Notice that the sequence $\big\{f(x_k)\big\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f(c)$ for some $c\in[a,b]$.

Because the sequence $$y_n=\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+...+f(x_n)}{n}$$ is the Cesaro Mean of the sequence $\big\{f(x_k)\big\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, then $y_n$ converges to the same $f(c)$ as above.