# If $f$ is continuous $\exists t: f(t)=\frac{f(x_1) + ... + f(x_n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following:

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and $\{x_1,...,x_n\} \subset [a,b]$. Prove that $\exists t \in [a,b]:$
> $$f(t)=\frac{f(x_1) + ... + f(x_n)}{n}$$

What I did was the following:

I first proved as a lemma that if $\{x_1,..,x_n\} \subset [a,b]$ then $\exists x \in [a,b]$:

$$x=\frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{n}$$

and then used this lemma with the intermediate value theorem to prove the result.

Is there a more straightforward and direct way of proving this?

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898476/if-fa-b-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continuous-for-any-x-1-x-n-in-a/3898487#3898487

Comment: A stronger result is: If $f([a,b])$ is an interval, then the result holds. Proof: Let $x_1,\dots ,x_n\in [a,b].$ Then $f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)\in f([a,b]).$ Since $f([a,b])$ is an interval, it is convex, hence any convex combination of points in $f([a,b])$ is in $f([a,b]).$ Thus

$$\frac{f(x_1)+\cdots + f(x_n)}{n} \in f([a,b]),$$

giving the result.